# How To Build A Basic Web Crawler To Pull Information From A Website

Tags: php

I  Build A Basic Web Crawler To Pull Information From A Website .
For it I create `simple_html_dom.php`.

Now my code is like

```
<?php
    include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
    $target_url = "http://www.example.com/";
    $html = new simple_html_dom();
    $html->load_file($target_url);
    foreach($html->find('a') as $link) {
        echo $link->href."<br />";
    }
?>
```

I get the error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test\test.php on line 3

what is the problem plz help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have copy paste this code . Wrong single and double quotes in your block of code. change `“` to `"` and `’` to `'` . Your correct block of code are :-

```
<?php
    include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
    $target_url = "http://www.example.com/";
    $html = new simple_html_dom();
    $html->load_file($target_url);
    foreach($html->find('a') as $link) {
        echo $link->href."<br />";
    }
?>
```

Comment: how to pull all the website .this code only pull info of the current page.

Comment: Here is the reference link it will be helpful to you. http://davidwalsh.name/curl-download and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365011/how-to-get-content-from-external-web-page-by-php. these exactly do the same thing. Your code only extract link from that web page..

Answer (score 0):

Your double quotes and single quotes are weird. I suspect a keyboard problem..

The normal single quote that PHP accepts is **'**, yours is **‘**

The normal double quote that PHP accepts is **"**, yours is **“**

Your fixed code would be:

```
<?php
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$target_url = "http://www.xyz.com/";
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($target_url);
foreach($html->find('a') as $link){
echo $link->href."<br />";
}
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just using wrong quotes for your string.

Wrong: `“string“`

Right: `"string"`

Or: `'string'`

Please check your keyboard settings

Answer (score 0):

from what you have pasted, your have not used a proper double quote to encapsulate your string `$target_url = "http://www.xyz.com/"`; use `"`