# How to file_get_contents from localhost/docker

Tags: php, docker, curl, localhost

I have tried everything from the front page of google.
I have tried curl.
I tried adjusting my php.ini.
I tried with 127.0.0.1
I tried with localhost
I tried adding in my docker compose

```
        extra_hosts:
        - "www.mywebsite.local:127.0.0.1"
```

Really, nothing I try work.
How can I `file_get_contents` from a local url.

When i curl inside my docker I get

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.53 (Debian) Server at 127.0.0.1 Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

What else is there that I can try ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to get content from external web page by php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365011/how-to-get-content-from-external-web-page-by-php)

Comment: No. Sadly it does not.

Comment: As i mentioned i already use `file_get_contents` but it does not work from 127.0.0.1

Comment: CAN you give more détails about the request?

Comment: `file_get_contents($url)` , `$url` being a localhost url

Comment: Like file_get_contents(‘index.php’) ? What about the request? Give an image.